# Create queue in azure queue only if queue not available using rest API

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I want create queue only if queue is not available in azure storage. I am using this **PutMessage** method to create message in queue. This method is working fine but problem is with me where I need to attach **CreateQueue** method.

My createqueue method is also working fine but I can't identify where need to add because when **PutMessage** calls request.GetResponse() then it generate error if queue is wrong. Thanks

```
public static void PutMessage(String queueName, String message)
        {
            String requestMethod = "POST";

            String urlPath = $"{queueName}/messages";

            String storageServiceVersion = "2017-11-09";
            String dateInRfc1123Format = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("R", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

            String messageText = $"<QueueMessage><MessageText>{message}</MessageText></QueueMessage>";
            UTF8Encoding utf8Encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
            Byte[] messageContent = utf8Encoding.GetBytes(messageText);
            Int32 messageLength = messageContent.Length;

            String canonicalizedHeaders = String.Format(
                    "x-ms-date:{0}\nx-ms-version:{1}",
                    dateInRfc1123Format,
                    storageServiceVersion);
            String canonicalizedResource = $"/{StorageAccountName}/{urlPath}";
            String stringToSign = $"{requestMethod}\n\n\n{messageLength}\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{canonicalizedHeaders}\n{canonicalizedResource}";
                    
            String authorizationHeader = CreateAuthorizationHeader(stringToSign);

            Uri uri = new Uri("https://" + StorageAccountName + ".queue.Azure.com/" + urlPath);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            request.Method = requestMethod;
            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-date", dateInRfc1123Format);

            request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", storageServiceVersion);

            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationHeader);
            request.ContentLength = messageLength;

            using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                requestStream.Write(messageContent, 0, messageLength);
            }

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                String requestId = response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"];
            }
        }
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are concerned about when you should be calling your create queue method. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, exactly the problem is we will decide on basis of message if queue not found then need to create queue first on azure queue after that add message.

Comment: Is this feasible using rest api call?

Comment: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the following code in try/catch block and check for `WebException`.

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
{
    String requestId = response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"];
}
```

If the queue does not exist, then you will get an error with `404 (Not Found)` response status. In this case you should try to create the queue and once you receive a successful response back, you should call your put message again.

Your code would look something like:

```
try
{
    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        String requestId = response.Headers["x-ms-request-id"];
    }
}
catch (WebException exception)
{
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) exception.Response;
    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        //Call your create queue method here...
        CreateQueue(queueName);
        //Once the operation is successful, call PutMessage again.
        PutMessage(queueName, message);
    }
    else 
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Please note that you can get other exceptions as well however in the context of this operation we will not try to handle them and simply rethrow those exceptions.